# appcenter command not found after successful global install

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

```
npm install -g appcenter-cli
```

I installed appcenter-cli with the above command. It gets installed successfully but I get error message while using the appcenter command. Says it 'appcenter' is not recognized.

Here is the full error messages:
On Windows CMD Promt:

> 'appcenter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

On VS Code Terminal:

> appcenter : The term 'appcenter' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - appcenter
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (appcenter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Windows 10
Node: 14.15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the execution environment for the batch command is not correctly set up (e.g., PATH does not contain the directory of the appcenter CLI)

You may try to follow these steps to fix it:
https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?